# Pdf with page cURL effect

Tags: android, pdf, android-viewpager, effect, page-curl

I'm developing a PDF viewer application and I'm interested in adding a page curl effect when users flip through the pages. I've conducted online searches but haven't found a clear solution for implementing this feature. Could someone provide guidance or direct me to resources on how to create a page curl effect in a PDF viewer? I'm using Java for Android development. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! I've tried a page curl effect library, but it only works with images. I aim to develop a PDF reader book with this effect using Java.

Comment: The answer probably depends a lot on how you are implementing your current PDF rendering logic. You might want to provide more details on that. After all, the page curl is not tied to the PDF -- you could do a page curl of a photo or any other content.